# popup when checkbox is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

During checkout on our estore we have various delivery options, for a certain delivery option we want to display a popup box when it's selected, the particular option checkbox is as follows:

```
<input id="delivery_option_22_6" class="delivery_option_radio" type="radio" name="delivery_option[22]" data-key="76," data-id_address="22" value="76,">
```

Can someone please tell me how to create a popup when this checkbox is selected, that display a message that we choose?

Thanks!

Comment: That's not a checkbox, it's a radio button. But anyway, since you have used the jQuery tag, use jQueryUI too: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/ - or were you asking for recommendations of a JavaScript tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

Use `onclick` for the radio buton (no JQuery required)

```
<input id="delivery_option_22_6" onclick="alert('message')" class="delivery_option_radio" type="radio" name="delivery_option[22]" data-key="76," data-id_address="22" value="76,">
```

Comment: agree, no need jquery if just pop up alert

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have jQuery in the script then

```
$('#delivery_option_22_6').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        // Show popup window
        alert("selected");
    }
});
```

For popup use this library

http://vodkabears.github.io/remodal/#

or this

http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

HTML:

```
<input id="delivery_option_22_6" class="delivery_option_radio"  type="radio" name="delivery_option[22]" data-key="76," data-id_address="22" value="76," data-popup="Test message">

<div class="popup" style="display:none"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('input[data-popup]').on('change', function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        // Popup function
        $('.popup').text($(this).data('popup')).show();
    }
})
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/L1Lmz8oo/

Comment: Use on click instead of on change.